# set variable in github workflow run context

Tags: workflow

```
run: |
      ContainerId=$(sudo docker ps -q -f name=${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}) &&
      ImageId=$(sudo docker inspect -f '{{.Image}}' $containerId) &&
      echo "miro" &&
      echo $(sudo docker ps -q -f name=${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}) &&
      echo $(sudo docker inspect -f '{{.Image}}' $containerId) &&
      echo $ContainerId &&
      echo $ImageId
```

There is processing docker container. So `sudo docker ps -q -f name=${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}` this command must return value. But in logs, there is only "miro". Why other things does not print in log?